# Python: Getting indexes of a particular series of integer elements in array

Tags: python, arrays

How i can get the position  of  4,3,6  present in this order in one array?

```
import numpy as np

# This is where i want find the position of the series
# as you can see  the series  are
#                                  here                 here                 here    

a = np.array([5,6,7, 5,4,7, 3,6,7, 4,3,6 ,1,2,3, 4,5,6, 4,3,6, 9,3,2, 3,4,4, 4,3,6])
```

The result i would  is:

```
[9 , 18 , 27 ]
```

my first solution is :

```
#the series i'm looking for 

se=[4,3,6]

#where append the results
r = []

for i in range(len(a)-2):

   if a[i+0] == se[0] and a[i+1] == se[1] and a[i+2] == se[2]:
       r.append(i)


print(r)
```

output:

```
[9,18,27]
```

How i can obtain this result in a fast way with large 'a'  array?

Thanks to all .

Comment: sorry  for the syntax error ... list out of range.

Comment: i have fixed it  , thanks.  There is a way to do it faster , with built-in function , something like numpy  ?

Comment: in the accepted answer approach 1 after `M = (arr[np.arange(Na-Nseq+1)[:,None] + r_seq] == seq).all(1)` add the line `return M.nonzero()[0]` that is what you need, delete the remaining lines